# Resource Intensive code fix

Tags: android

I have the following piece of code running on a picture. It produces the following error. I am assuming it is because the code takes a few seconds to run and then crashes so must be too much for the cpu to handle. I would like to ask how would I modify this code so it completes in <1second and is less intensive and so it doesnt crash. Thanks. Alex

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                   Process: cartoonify.alexcz.cartoonify, PID: 25764
                                                   java.lang.IllegalStateException
                                                   at android.graphics.Bitmap.setPixels(Bitmap.java:1626)
                                                   at cartoonify.alexcz.cartoonify.Main$2.onClick(Main.java:111)
```

---

```
change_pic.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if(picturePresent == true){

                    int r,g,b,colour;

                    int [] allpixels = new int [picture.getHeight() * picture.getWidth()];

                    picture.getPixels(allpixels, 0, picture.getWidth(), 0, 0, picture.getWidth(), picture.getHeight());

                    for(int i = 0; i < allpixels.length; i++)
                    {
                        colour = allpixels[i];
                        r = Color.red(colour);
                        b = Color.blue(colour);
                        g = Color.green(colour);

                        if(r < FIRSTSECTION){
                                r = FIRST;
                        }else if(r >= SECONDSECTION && r < THIRDSECTION){
                                r = SECOND;
                        }else if(r >= THIRDSECTION && r < FOURTHSECTION){
                                r = THIRD;
                        }else if(r >= FOURTHSECTION && r < FIFTHSECTION){
                                r = FORTH;
                        }

                        if(b < FIRSTSECTION){
                            b = FIRST;
                        }else if(b >= SECONDSECTION && b < THIRDSECTION){
                            b = SECOND;
                        }else if(b >= THIRDSECTION && b < FOURTHSECTION){
                            b = THIRD;
                        }else if(b >= FOURTHSECTION && b < FIFTHSECTION){
                            b = FORTH;
                        }

                        if(g < FIRSTSECTION){
                            g = FIRST;
                        }else if(g >= SECONDSECTION && g < THIRDSECTION){
                            g = SECOND;
                        }else if(g >= THIRDSECTION && g < FOURTHSECTION){
                            g = THIRD;
                        }else if(g >= FOURTHSECTION && g < FIFTHSECTION){
                            g = FORTH;
                        }

                        allpixels[i] = Color.argb(1, r, g, b);

                    }

                    picture.setPixels(allpixels, 0, picture.getWidth(), 0, 0, picture.getWidth(), picture.getHeight());
                    drawableBitmap = new BitmapDrawable(getResources(), picture);
                    image.setBackground(drawableBitmap);
                }
            }
        });
```

Comment: Looks Like it to me. Here's the Android doc on IllegalStateException. https://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/IllegalStateException.html

Comment: Please check if "picture" is mutable: add the following to onClick(), preferably before the `setPixels(...)` statement: `Log.d("CHECK", "pic is mutable " + picture.isMutable() );`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`setPixels` requires a mutable Bitmap, otherwise you will get an `IllegalStateException`. See [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html#setPixel%28int,%20int,%20int%29).

You should copy or create a new bitmap, and make it mutable:

To create a new mutable bitmap:

```
Bitmap newBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(originalWidth, originalHeight, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
```

Or to copy and make a mutable bitmap:

```
boolean isMutable = true;
Bitmap newBitmap = originalBitmap.copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888, isMutable);
```

Now you will be able to use `newBitmap.setPixels(...)`

If this is an expensive operation, you should consider doing it in a background thread (e.g. `AsyncTask`).